# How to shorten a file path name?

Tags: r, filepath

My teacher was able to shorten his file path as shown below

```
save(t,file="./Data/data.RData")load(url("website.RData"))
```

Every time I tried this in R, it gave me an error. I'm not sure if I'm just typing it out wrong, or if it's because I'm using a mac and he is using a PC.

```
save(q, file="./Documents/Documents - My MacBook Pro/STATS - R Programming/class_folder/Project_2/q.RData")

# output
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file './Documents/Documents - My MacBook Pro/STATS - R Programming/class_folder/Project_2/q.RData', probable reason 'Invalid argument'
```

Comment: The path doesn’t exist. Your teacher’s exists (on their computer). That’s why it works for them but not for you.

Comment: First do `getwd()`, then set your working directory to where the file is and do `getwd()`---ensure that the `.` directory has the correct path to the file. Also make sure the file has the name `q.RData` your teacher has `data.RData`.

Comment: @Baraliuh It’s generally considered very bad advice to tamper with the working directory; it’s also completely unnecessary — in other words, *don’t call `setwd()`*.

Comment: I dunno, each Rproject I have has its own wd. Never given me any trouble.

Comment: @Baraliuh You’re mixing *project directory* and *working directory*. These are distinct. Admittedly R makes this confusing because R’s conception of a project directory is beyond primitive. However, as a general rule the working directory is controlled by the *user* of your code, when they launch it. Code should never make assumptions about the current working directory, this only leads to trouble. See also https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/#whats-wrong-with-setwd.

Comment: I really am not. To R they are both wd since the wd is just a pointer on your hard-drive. You default wd will not change with `setwd()` once you restart R. There really are no problems with chaining you wd as need. If you want a hard reset just add `on.exit`. `old <- setwd('new_wd'); on.exit(setwd(old))`

Comment: The only relevance of that blog is that you make an Rproj rather than pointing to a directory... Clearly, that is the best choice for getting the default wd need in a contained project. But in Rprojects it can be convenient to change folders. E.g., if you have a script that saves all project figures, it is more convenient to change folder then pasting strings/writing out folder path for each figure.

Comment: @Baraliuh You must be reading a different article. The one I linked to clearly says that `setwd()` has a 0% chance of doing what you want on any computer except your own, and not even on your own a few months from now. Granted, this is specifically talking about absolute paths (and relative paths don’t have the same issues) but you, too, seem to be talking about absolute paths, since using relative paths doesn’t apply in OP’s situation. And of course the real issue here is the presence of absolute paths, not merely `setwd()`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  R has *no* concept of a project directory.  RStudio does, but R doesn't.

Comment: @user2554330 I was being diplomatic.

Comment: Yet I have reproducible and published R-code with `setwd()` that runs on any computer. Weird with 0 % chance. The real issue here is determining if the (relative) path to the file is correct. Clearly, it has nothing to do with producing code that can run no different computers. Hence, using `getwd()` or `setwd()` is not a problem. I read the article, and I understood it, I do not get if u do not understand the question asked or the article.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer with precision as it is by definition not reproducible, but on a Mac try using `~`, for instance:

```
filepath <- "~username/Downloads/test.csv"
read.csv(filepath)
```

You can test this by saving a CSV in called `test.csv` in your downloads folder and replacing `username` with your user name.